# Substore inner page 404 page errors

Tags: magento-enterprise

I setup one Magento on Mypeer1.com server.
My magento is having multistore with all the design layout same and just the category and theme color is different and i am going to have separate domain for each of my store.

everything is working fine on my staging server , so i moved on Mypeer1.com
For now the site is in testing mode and not mapped to the domain so its working temporary in IP address.

The main site is working fine e.g
122.122.232.12 and the inner store is setup like
122.122.232.12/store2 and same as other store 122.122.232.12/store3 and 122.122.232.12/store4

now  the issue is all other store is working for only home page and when i open the inner pages for all other store , it load the main store theme with 404 page.

I have placed the correct htaccess in the substore folder and setup the correct store code and other settings correctly. I am not sure why its loading home page for all sotre and not loading the inner page as well as any category and product pages.

Any help will be very much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Pravin, did you get this fixed? I am having the same problem. I have checked my base urls, index.php for MAGE_RUN_CODE and mod_rewrite is enabled. What else can I check to fix this? I'm running out of ideas how to solve this.

Comment: Hi Pravin, Is your problem solved.  Now we have the same issue.  kindly tell how you have solved the issue?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the following:

- Check and set the base-urls (example.com), maybe you missed the trailing slash in your stores?
- Create an entry for testing in your hosts-file (under Windows in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts), so you can test with a domain and not IP-address

  122.122.232.12   example.com
- you talked about substore folders: Does this mean you have subfolders like `store2, store3, store4,...` where you set the `MAGE_RUN_CODE`? Check if you've got maybe the wrong address/ip in the RewriteCond.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `mod_rewrite` enabled on your server.

Comment: I already checked it and its enable.

Comment: What about `AllowOverride All`?  If it's set to `None` then it will ignore your .htaccess